# How to Segment Accelerometer Signal at idle points

Tags: arduino-ide, accelerometer, signal-processing

I'm using an 3 axis Accelerometer(GY-521) to get the acceleration data and also the gyroscope to get the gyro data. I want to segment the signals at the idle points so that i can get the segmented signal at the idle points.

[image]

Is there any algorithm or example code that i could use to segment this kind of signal?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want the final result to look like?

Comment: Hi brett, i want the signal segments that are not in the idle state to be identified and analyze them. Im doing this to identify gestures through accelerometer and gyroscope.

Answer (score 2):

There are many algorithms you can use. I would advise you to look carefully at the data and the "idle state" and see what is always different. Try everything you can think of and see what works best, or if one does everything you need just stop there.

It might be that you can just calculate if the accelerometer values go over a certain threshold, but that requires that either the orientation be know or the threshold being over 1g.

You could also calculate the rate at which the accerometer value is changing by subtracting the last value (the derivative if you are up on your calculus) and threshold that value, which might produce better results.

You could also calculate a running average and then compare the current value with that. If the numbers match (or are very close) then you can say the accelerometer has been idle. This has the effect of making a changing threshold relative to the most recent activity tuned by the average's response.

I doubt any of these will be perfect, so you might require the algorithm to say "idle" multiple times in a row before changing state from "active" to "idle", or something to that effect.